# Hosting CiviCRM and Wordpress on WPengine

Tags: wordpress, hosting, hosting-providers

I'm just starting a new implementation project with a client who uses WordPress and hosts currently with WPengine.com
A quick search threw up some interesting comments [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/in-wordpress-i-want-to-convert-my-installation-from-an-external-database-to-use) from @andrew-hunt that don't bode well.

Does anyone have direct experience (good or bad) of running CiviCRM 4.6.x on WPengine's platform? Should I be advising my client that we need to find an alternative hosting provider?

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of test sites running on WP Engine.   Mostly to fix an issue that came uo in CiviCRM 4.7.x.   I have installed and configured 4.6 on WP Engine.   My only issue had been they used to have many sites on php 5.3.3  but I am mostly seeing 5.5 these days.   I know CiviCRM has some issues with HHVM, so you would need to verify that your client site is not running that.  I have not used WP Engine in production yet.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue for a site. I get en error that cron is not running on the 4.7.11
Is it not adviced to run CiviCRM on WP Engine?

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend it. We found that the WPEngine platform and Civi weren't going to work the way we need them too. We tried this under their P1 plan. In sum, just too many restrictions, which is totally understandable for WPEngine to make WP work so well there.

*Max Execution time for imports and other server setting restrictions (if you are on shared hosting plan then this would be limited to 60s.)

*Had issues getting cron jobs setup

*System status page did not show

*Weird behavior with not showing some Civi content for ACL users on some pages. Had to give permission in User Role Editor WP page and post access as workaround.

Have to let their platform specialize in what they are good at. I've absolutely loved the WPEngine platform; nothing better for WP. But just not for Civi.

We ended up keeping our CMS multisite at WPEngine and using Civihosting for a WP + CiviCRM multisite mirroring each other.